# Windows form application to change wallpaper. But it changes to black

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] allFiles = new string[10];
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet =CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, string pvParam, uint fWinIni);
        const uint SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
        const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;
        }
    private void OnPowerChange(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Mode) {
            case PowerModes.Resume:
            var result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, @"F:\abc", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                string wp = GetWPPath();
                Console.WriteLine(wp);
                break;
            case PowerModes.Suspend:
                var res = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, @"F:\abc", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
                break;
        }

    }
    private static string GetWPPath()
    {
        RegistryKey wallpaper = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false);
        string wp_path = wallpaper.GetValue("WallPaper").ToString();
        wallpaper.Close();
        return wp_path;
    }
```

I want to change the wallpaper when i resume laptop from sleep or hibernate. I also checked the registry key, it shows the wallpaper as the path I've set but the desktop background is just black. Is there some kind of reg keys that I have to change or something?

Edit: I hardcoded the file as @"F:\abc", that's the problem. Changed it by mentioning the extension too like @"F:\abc.jpg" and it works. Anyways, I'm gonna change it to an input so shouldn't be a problem. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix i don't understand what's wrong with my post? Is the question unclear?

Comment: Well the title is noisy.  *Can somebody please help me* is useless clutter (so is the `C#` there).  Every question here wants help, if they all did that, the noise ratio would skyrocket.  But mainly, you agreed to read those when you signed up, and had not done so.

Comment: Is there a chance the file is inaccessible while sleeping/resuming, such as on a shared drive, or a removable drive which is powered down, disconnected, etc in your computer's power settings to reserve power?

Comment: @QZSupport Nope. I've set myhard disk to never turn off

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do it in console. It works for  me. And later you can add your app to windows autoload.

You must add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

```
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction,
           int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

        private static readonly int MAX_PATH = 260;
        private static readonly int SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x73;
        private static readonly int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
        private static readonly int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        private static readonly int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        static string GetDesktopWallpaper()
        {
            string wallpaper = new string('\0', MAX_PATH);
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, (int)wallpaper.Length, wallpaper, 0);
            return wallpaper.Substring(0, wallpaper.IndexOf('\0'));
        }

        static void SetDesktopWallpaper(string filename)
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, filename,
                SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
            //should be like - C:\img.jpg
            SetDesktopWallpaper(Console.ReadLine());

        }    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you the for the code. I had done something similar to what you did earlier in a previous program. I am just trying this out to make it change the wallpaper upon resume from sleep or startup. Is there anything wrong in my code? Like what's the issue any idea?

Comment: I think you should develop something easyer (like my code) and just autoload your programs. Read about this [here](http://www.howto-connect.com/windows-10-run-program-automatically-at-startup/)

Comment: Hmm.. No.. You wrote about "sleep".

Comment: i know how to make run upon startup. Added it in the registry. But unable to figure out why it's not changing to the file I set.